# Traversing and Printing a Binary Tree Level by Level

Tags: c++, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I am trying to traverse a binary tree built with the input data from keyboard. Data is inserted to the binary tree successfully. I have a switch statement, where 'case 4' should traverse (and print) the binary tree level by level. However I got EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I would be more than happy if someone help me out with this one.

(RootPtr is the top -Level 0- node of the binary tree defined globally; TreeDepth() is the function calculating "Depth" of the tree where Depth defined globally and root node has depth of 0; and GetNode is basically an initializer function (using malloc) for type TreePtr pointers.)

Thank you all in advance.

Here is the relevant code:

This is the struct definition;

```
    typedef struct treeItem
{
    int data;
    struct treeItem *left;
    struct treeItem *right;

}Tree , *TreePtr;
```

This is the switch case where I call Level by Level traversing function(s);

```
case 4:
                TreePtr temp;
                GetNode(&temp);

                temp = RootPtr;

                printLevelOrder(temp);
                printf("\n\n");

                break;
```

These are the functions used for traversing the tree level by level;

```
void printGivenLevel(TreePtr TemPtr, int level)
{
    if (items == 0)
        return;
    else
    {    if(level == 0 )
        {
            printf(" %d", (*TemPtr).data); //the line I got ERROR
        }
        else
        {
            printGivenLevel((*TemPtr).left, (level-1));
            printGivenLevel((*TemPtr).right, (level-1));
        }
    }
}

void printLevelOrder(TreePtr TemPtr)
{
    TreeDepth();
    if (items == 0)
        printf("\nTree is empty.\n");
    else
    {
        printf("Traverse level by level:");

        for (int i=0; i<=Depth; i++)
        {
            printGivenLevel(TemPtr, i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Super busy so can't dig in, but wouldn't breadth first search work here?

Comment: @kiss-o-matic Honestly I'm a beginner, so for the first moment I could not picture 'breadth first search' in my mind. But I will research it. Thank you.

Comment: @BasakOguz https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Answer (score 1):

It's an off by one error. In your for loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<=Depth; i++)
```

You're traversing this loop `Depth + 1` times. This means you're trying to access one more level than there actually is. In particular, in the final call of `printGivenLevel`, in the point in the recursion where `level == 1`, you're already at the bottom of the tree. You're now recursing one more time, but the pointers you pass into the next recursion level are garbage pointers (they aren't guaranteed to point to memory you're allowed to access, or even exists). So when you try to dereference them, you get an error.

One more thing: this implementation is pretty inefficient, since you're traversing the tree many times. It's better to do a breadth-first search, like kiss-o-matic mentioned. This way, you'll only traverse the tree once, which is much faster (although it does use more memory).

Comment: Hello. I started the value of Depth from 0; in other words if there is only one node (which in this case will be the root node), Depth has the value of 0. With that information, is the `for (int i=0; i<=Depth; i++)`  loop still trying to reach Depth+1 times?

Comment: @BasakOguz the for loop will always run through `Depth+1` iterations. However, if the `Depth` variable is actually defined as the "level" of the deepest node, than that's actually OK...

Comment: @BasakOguz can you share the code that calculates `Depth`?

Comment: Actually I calculate depth of the left side of the root `ldepth` and depth of the right side of the root `rdepth` in the `Insertion()` function, where the input data from keyboard is inserted to the tree. Then in the `Depth()` function I find the depth of the tree by comparing these two (greater one would be the depth of the tree). However I believe, what you would like to see is the `Insertion()` function and it would be an extremely long post for here. Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: As I said, `Depth` is starting from 0. If I start the for loop from `i=1` or end it when `i<Depth` (not `i<=Depth`), it does not print the root node. Also it still gives the same ERROR when more nodes are added.

Comment: @BasakOguz If `ldepth` and `rdepth` aren't actually equal, **that's** your problem! I was assuming you had a full binary tree (all leaves are at the same depth). But if that's not the case, then printing all the data at a certain level will obviously start failing at some point, because in some parts of the tree, that data doesn't exist!

Comment: This is a given assignment unfortunately, which makes it my problem of course. I'm a beginner and worked hard for this one until this point and now I have a problem, seeking for help as many else here. So I would be glad if you have any suggestion for an unbalanced tree.

Comment: @BasakOguz I was gonna make an edit to my answer to give a solution for an unbalanced tree. But if you've solved it on your own, that's even better! Congratulations :)